# Electron - is it possible to make application loaded from internet

Tags: electron, progressive-web-apps, loaded

I know that it is not the case for Electron is made but if there is a possibility to load for e.g. an angular app (PWA) which is hosted on the Internet to the electron?
The effect I want to reach is loading application when Electron is starting up - not building the image with application installed on.

I know that PWA are installable via browser but I want an .exe application installed on client computers which updates every web application deploy.

Comment: can you just create a BrowserWindow in electron and point it to your site? `loadURL(website)`?

Comment: Thank you very very much, my question was so noobie :)